# add values based on distinct values of another column from table with multiple records

Tags: mysql, database, sum, distinct

I have a table like

> [image: Blockquote]

and i want to summaries like this

[image]

So i want to sum packages for distinct items where my table could have multiple records that i can not just exclude cause are different.

I can not just

```
select sum(package) from table group by buyer,item;
```

and i can not also devide it with the count(item).

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) , as a image is not a **easy** reproducible example..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use a subquery

```
select sum(package), buyer
from (
  select distinct buyer, package
  from my_table  ) t
group by buyer
```